# Use order by field for certain field, but keep order in date field - MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in MySQL and it has two very important fields STATUS and DATE.

In the STATUS field values can be "wait", 'ok", "2edit", or "no", so to get the values i use "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY FIELD(request_status, 'wait', '2edit', 'ok', 'no')"

So far so good. But I need the results that have STATUS = "wait", to be in DATE order. Is it possible?

I hope I have passed the idea!

Thank you.

Comment: ORDER BY CASE WHEN... THEN... END

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofcourse this is possible =)

Take a look at 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY FIELD(request_status, 'wait', '2edit', 'ok', 'no'), `DATE` ASC|DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add a second sorting condition:

```
... ORDER BY
      FIELD(request_status, 'wait', '2edit', 'ok', 'no'),
      `date`
```

In case you did not want to alter the order of row where `request_status <> 'wait'`, you could do this (but formally, this does not make sense, because the order of rows is officially undefined without an ORDER BY clause):

```
... ORDER BY
      FIELD(request_status, 'wait', '2edit', 'ok', 'no'),
      IF(request_status = 'wait', `date`, 0)
```

... but you shouldn't do either version, as such a query is unable to use any index to honor the `ORDER BY` clause. This is because of the function call that needs to be made for each and every row to be sorted.

Instead, you should add an `order` field with a proper index on it, and `ORDER BY` this field. Then your final query would look like this:

```
... ORDER BY request_status_order, `date`
```

And if you want to comply with the normalisation best practices, extract your statuses into a  new `status` table. Join your main table with this table. Use the desired order index as a primary key for this new table.

```
CREATE TABLE statuses (
    status_index INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    label VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE main_table (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    status_index INT NOT NULL,
    other_fields VARCHAR(10),
    CONSTRAINT fk_status FOREIGN KEY fk_status_idx (status_index)
        REFERENCES statuses (status_index)
);

SELECT * FROM main_table
JOIN statuses USING (status_index)
ORDER BY status_index, `date`;
```

Comment: I like the normalization, because this is really needed when performance is required.

Answer (score 1):

You can generally sort the data according to `date` after sorting by `request_status`

```
SELECT * FROM table 
ORDER BY FIELD(request_status, 'wait', '2edit', 'ok', 'no'), 
         `date`
```

Comment: + but note, all `request_status`es will be in ascending `date` order. Not just `wait`. However, there is no other alternative. This is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work.  The second part of the if statement doesn't matter, as long as it's a date.

```
select * from table 
ORDER BY FIELD(request_status, 'wait', '2edit', 'ok', 'no'),
if(request_status = 'wait', date, '2013-01-01')
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bfbf7/11)